# Vue.js image src binding / switch statement

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

new to Vue.js, wondering if this code I have written is valid and would function as expected. I am working on a project that has numerous "brands" so based on the brand name that is coming from vue.store the image related to that brand would show. This works when binding class to an element but I have not yet tried with :src binding images based on switch case. Is there a better way to achieve this?

HTML:

```
  <img :src="brandImg" class="brandImgOne" alt=brand "image" />
```

js:

```
computed: {
   brandImg() {
      let brandImg = '';
      let thisBrand = this.$store.state.ui.theme.brand;
      switch (thisBrand) {
          case 'brandOne':
          brandIcon = '/img/iconOne.png';
          break;
          case 'brandTwo':
          brandIcon = '/img/iconTwo.png';
          break;
          case 'brandThree':
          brandIcon = '/img/iconThree.png';
          break;
          default:
          console.warn('not configured`);
          break;
      }
         return brandIcon;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Hi!, i dont know what do you want with that alt in the <img>

And yes probably, will work, make the return in the case
   case 'brandOne':
   return '/iconOne.png';
But doesnt matter

Comment: @Ignacio, thank you for the input :)...the alt was a typo...lol...yes this seems to work fine with the brand pages. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return the values on the switch like this:

```
computed: {
   brandImg() {
      let brandImg = '';
      let thisBrand = this.$store.state.ui.theme.brand;
      switch (thisBrand) {
          case 'brandOne':
          return '/img/iconOne.png';
          case 'brandTwo':
          return '/img/iconTwo.png';
          case 'brandThree':
          return '/img/iconThree.png';
          default:
          console.warn('not configured`);
          break;
      }
     }
   }
```